# Apache camel 2.17 No consumer available on end point using spring context

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel

Getting no consumers available at end point while inter connecting two different camel contexts. 
JBoss Fuse 6.3
EAP server 6.4
Package: War

Camel Context 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd                   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring                 http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="file:C:/Temp/Selva/inbox?noop=true"/>
            <log id="_log1" loggingLevel="INFO" message=" Proxy Route..!!! "/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="direct-vm:inProvider"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Camel Context2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring                            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <camelContext  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="direct-vm:inProvider"/>
            <log id="_log1" loggingLevel="INFO" message="Modelling Platform Router..!!! "/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="file:C:/Users/cpiespc/Selva/outbox"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
      <display-name>CamelContext</display-name>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: Please add full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect via `direct-vm` on JBoss EAP as the classloader isolation will prevent that when deploying as WAR files.

You may be able to do it via wildfly-camel sub-modules, but I don't know, but you can ask that team: https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel

Comment: Is there any alternative with which I can connect two different camel context as WAR deployment within same JVM? In the VM documentation http://camel.apache.org/vm.html, in the sample section it has shown connecting two different context with two different WAR application which is bit confusing. Is the issue only in case with direct-vm?